# Obtaining intermediate layers' activation values given input example(s)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network

Suppose I have defined my sequential model as follow:

```
require 'nn'
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 6, 5, 5)) -- 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 5x5 convolution kernel
net:add(nn.ReLU())                       -- non-linearity 
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))     -- A max-pooling operation that looks at 2x2 windows and finds the max.
net:add(nn.SpatialConvolution(6, 16, 5, 5))
net:add(nn.ReLU())                       -- non-linearity 
net:add(nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2,2,2,2))
net:add(nn.View(16*5*5))                    -- reshapes from a 3D tensor of 16x5x5 into 1D tensor of 16*5*5
net:add(nn.Linear(16*5*5, 120))             -- fully connected layer (matrix multiplication between input and weights)
net:add(nn.ReLU())                       -- non-linearity 
net:add(nn.Linear(120, 84))
net:add(nn.ReLU())                       -- non-linearity 
net:add(nn.Linear(84, 10))                   -- 10 is the number of outputs of the network (in this case, 10 digits)
net:add(nn.LogSoftMax())                     -- converts the output to a log-probability. Useful for classification problems
```

And here's the model printed:

```
net
nn.Sequential {
  [input -> (1) -> (2) -> (3) -> (4) -> (5) -> (6) -> (7) -> (8) -> (9) -> (10) -> (11) -> (12) -> (13) -> output]
  (1): nn.SpatialConvolution(1 -> 6, 5x5)
  (2): nn.ReLU
  (3): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2,2)
  (4): nn.SpatialConvolution(6 -> 16, 5x5)
  (5): nn.ReLU
  (6): nn.SpatialMaxPooling(2x2, 2,2)
  (7): nn.View(400)
  (8): nn.Linear(400 -> 120)
  (9): nn.ReLU
  (10): nn.Linear(120 -> 84)
  (11): nn.ReLU
  (12): nn.Linear(84 -> 10)
  (13): nn.LogSoftMax
}
```

Simply using `net:forward(input)` returns the last layer's output after LogSoftMax has been applied to which is what I do not want. Instead, I would like to get the activations of some of the intermediate layers (e.g. module 6).

So, How can I get the activations of each of the intermediate layers when feeding an input? i.e. I feed an input example to the network and want to extract the activation results of the 6th layer (a convolutional layer), not just the final layer.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via `net:get(6).output` (see [get](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/containers.md#getindex) and [output](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/module.md#output)).